# One line if else statement refuses to work

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, syntax, syntax-error

Sorry for submitting a question this small but it's driving me nuts. I have this single line which is permanently giving me syntax error:

```
print(BDF) if header is 1
```

I've also tried this:

```
print(BDF) if (header == 1)
```

Here's the full function:

```
def CSVtoDict(BDF, prune, header):
    # Comes with the option to prune [] and to use headers
    with open('%s%s.csv' % (dataDir,BDF), mode='r') as infile:
        reader = csv.reader(infile)
        saved = {}
        for row in reader:
            key = row[0]
            saved[key] = [r for r in row[1:] if not (r is '' and prune is 1)]
        print(BDF) if header is 1
    return saved
```

What could possibly be causing this? I'm calling the function with:

```
adsMut = CSVtoDict(BaseDataFiles[0],1,1)
```

Everything seems to be in order, it just gives me syntax error every time.

Comment: Why are you trying to be fancy with a `print` statement? Just do the most simple and straight-forward solution (John Gordon's answer). How much time have you spent debugging this? And anyone who reads the one liner solution will have to wonder about why you are doing it this way.

Comment: It's a very simple line, making it two lines wouldn't make the code any more clearer (I think) and would make it needlessly longer (line-wise). Also I want to perfect the basics as I go into more complex stuff :)

Comment: I strongly believe that using ternary conditional operator like is not standard; the syntax is a bit confusing, right? Otherwise you would not be asking this question. And if you go with `print(BDF) if header is 1 else None`, `None` will get printed if the condition is not satisfied, do you want that?

Comment: Oh, that's fair. But then why won't using `else pass` work?

Comment: @Akavall No, `None` won't be printed.  You're misreading the expression as `print(BDF if header is 1 else None)`.

Comment: Oh right, I thought that'd be weird, thanks

Comment: @JohnGordon are you sure? `print None` will print `None`, and  `BDF if header is 1 else None` will evaluate to `None` if `header is 1` is `False`. Running `print "Hi" if 2 == 3 else None` does print `None`.

Comment: @Akavall this question was tagged as Python 3, so `print()` is a function.  `print(BDF)` is evaluated as one unit; it won't pick up the `None` value.

Comment: @JohnGordon, I see in Python 3 it is different. Thank You.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to provide `else` clause as well for this one liner. Following line will work:

```
print(BDF) if header is 1 else None
```

Comment: That was it, thanks! I forgot that you can't use "pass" but rather have to use None in these cases. Thanks you so much this has saved me like half an hour of frustration! :)

Answer (score 6):

Any special reason you're using the one-line `if` format?  The more usual format is:

```
if header == 1:
    print (BDF)
```

Comment: I want to make my code prettier, but the one line format refuses to work :(

Comment: As Ahsanul answered above, the one-line format requires an `else`.  Given that restriction, I'm not sure it is prettier for your code.

Comment: Are you sure? I'd rather write an extra else than an extra whole line... maybe it's just me though

Comment: Let me remind 2 rules from `import this` zen. `Beautiful is better than ugly.` and `Simple is better than complex.`. In your particular case, one-liner doesn't make your code cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

```
a if condition else b
```

Use the ternary conditional operator for python